# How to reset the entire networking config changes?

Tags: networking, network-bridge

Well, after I crashed into a not-helpful tutorial (about KVM networking) and not-helpful tech guys on Serverfault, I ended up totally spoiling my Ubuntu environment, lmao. Like, I ran these commands and files:

```
sudo nano /etc/netplan/01-netcfg.yaml
# edited randomly, for the countless times
```

```
sudo nmcli con add type bridge-slave ifname enp2s0 master br0
```

```
sudo netplan apply
```

Now, I'm over. `sudo brctl delbr br0` simply doesn't work (it says "it's still up can't delete" or like that) and my entire network, interface settings glitches within the machine. I tried reconnecting the lan cable or rebooting the machine for number of times, well it keeps showing the same random something on `ip a`.

I simply need a command that magically (factory) resets these random changes (instead of factory reset the entire machine, if possible haha...). Any chance? Thanks for your help.

Comment: Netplan isn't omniscient, it is possible to make changes in it that can't be fully applied without rebooting.   But if your netplan config is wrong, it might be easiest to just delete it (or move it to another directory) and reboot and see if network manager takes over.

Comment: Hi. I guess the configs were not wrong (from wrong I mean they were gramatically correct, while they were indeed wrong as they worked in the way I didn't expect), and so maybe that's why even after I deleted the content of the file and re-applied, didn't get reverted, then rebooting, still not getting reverted. Like that.